# How to transition from nested UIPageViewController into a presented UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a transition between a `UIViewController` in a nested `UIPageViewController`, to a new instance of this same `UIPageViewController`.

To make it more clear, an image of what I try to achieve:

[image: mockup]

What I currently have is a `UIViewController`, which has the view of the `UIPageViewController` as a subview.

The `UIPageViewController` consists of `UIViewController`s which view is a `UIImageView`.

Now when I tap on one of the pages in the that `UIPageViewController`, it show a new instance of this same `UIPageViewController`.

#### My implementation:

I customized the transition from the presenting to the presented view controller.

Then I discovered there's no *from* `UIViewController` in the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, so I passed that manually to my animator class.

**My source controller:**

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    var animator = Animator()

    var photosViewController: ProfilePhotosViewController!

    var model: Person!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

        self.photosViewController = ProfilePhotosViewController()
        self.photosViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
        self.addChildViewController(self.photosViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.photosViewController.view)
        self.photosViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.photosViewController.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        let views = ["imageView": self.photosViewController.view]
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[imageView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[imageView(==200)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

        self.photosViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapHandler:")))
    }

    func tapHandler(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let photosViewController = ProfilePhotosViewController()

        photosViewController.photos = self.model.photos
        photosViewController.index = self.photosViewController.index

        photosViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
        photosViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        self.photosViewController.viewControllers.first!.presentViewController(photosViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController,
                             presentingController presenting: UIViewController,
                                     sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.animator.presentingController = source
        return self.animator
    }

}
```

**My Animator class:**

```
class Animator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    var presentingController: UIViewController?

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.25
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        var toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!
        var toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

        var fromViewController = self.presentingController!
        var fromView = fromViewController.view

        transitionContext.containerView().addSubview(toView)

        let snapshotFrame = (fromView as! UIImageView).imageFrame
        let snapshot: UIView? = fromView?.resizableSnapshotViewFromRect(snapshotFrame, afterScreenUpdates: false, withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero)
        snapshot!.frame = fromView!.convertRect(snapshotFrame, toView: toView)
        transitionContext.containerView().addSubview(snapshot!)

        fromView.hidden = true

        toView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0)

        (toView.subviews[0] as! UIView).hidden = true

        let fromImageViewController = (toViewController as? ProfilePhotosViewController)!.viewControllers.first
        let fromImageView = fromImageViewController?.view as! UIImageView

        toView.layoutIfNeeded()

        var toImageFrame = fromImageView.imageFrame

        UIView.animateWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: {
            toView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(1)

            snapshot?.frame = toImageFrame

            }, completion: { finished in
                (toView.subviews[0] as! UIView).hidden = false
                fromView?.hidden = false
                snapshot?.removeFromSuperview()
                transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
        })
    }

}
```

*N.B. `imageFrame` is [an extension on `UIImageView`](https://gist.github.com/koenpunt/7c6b76f719680a49955d), which returns the actual frame of the displayed `UIImage`.*

Although this does work, I have a feeling this is not best practice.

**So any pointers in what I could do better here are appreciated.**

Things like;

- is a modally presented view controller the correct solution, or should I go with a customized push/pop transition?
- do I actually need to create a new instance of this view controller, or is there a way to let it "pop" out of the current view?

Comment: you found any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, also haven't been doing a lot of iOS development lately..